# Prevent hyphenation

Tags: sectioning, hyphenation

The page has a lot of space but subsection hyphenated. How to prevent this?
[image]

I need to stretch that title.

Comment: I see the next line ending at the same level as the hyphen, so that's the line width.

Comment: Which version of LaTeX do you use? How wide is the text block? Which packages did you load that possibly affect the ability to hyphenate words in sectioning headers?

Comment: Add `\raggedright` to the formatting instructions applied to this specific heading.